# Input field with type="number" allows specials characters in Firefox works fine in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, firefox, input

Input field with type="number" allows specials characters in Firefox works fine in Chrome and Edge.

In this input field I need to enter only numbers and restrict user from entering any special characters and alphabets.

```
 <input type="number" name="height" class="form-control input-number"  ng-model="height" tabindex="11" min="0" data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,10}$/" data-ng-keydown="checkForNumber($event)">
```

The JS function

```
 $scope.checkForNumber = function(event) {
         if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190) {

         } else {
            event.preventDefault();
         }
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0]
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (isNaN(input.value)) {
    input.value = input.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="height" class="form-control input-number" ng-model="height" tabindex="11" min="0" data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,10}$/">
```

The js listens for an input. If there is an input, it checks if it is a number. If it isn't, it strips all non-numbers.

Comment: Hi , this doesn't seem to work again in firefox alone @Endothermic_Dragon

Comment: Fixed it! Now it should work. Thanks for specifying the browser!