# FireFox or Safari + JavaScript Parses an Input Field Type Number Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, parsefloat

If you have a form field type of `number` and use that value in JavaScript, the results are not always consistent (with FireFox and Safari so far.)

A value of `10.0` in the input field will parse correctly as the floating number `10.0`.  However, if you have a "naked" decimal (e.g. `10.`) it will parse as `NaN`.

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606508/input-field-with-type-number-allows-specials-characters-in-firefox-works-fine) is similar, it does not address the contextual help I would like to use with `reportValidity()` and `checkValidity()`.  My intended eventual use is to leverage `.on('input change', function (e) {//do processing here});`.

I have included a Fiddle of an MRE as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/lbussy/rv0swbox/

In FF and Safari:

- `1` parses as `1`
- `1.` parses as `NaN`
- `1.0` parses as `1`

And pointing this out again: I do not want to use a text field and then parse it to a number because it eliminates the functionality inherent in the number type.

So, I want to use a number field for the functionality (and this should work!)  I will also recalculate other fields as the user types, so there will be an `.on('input change')` handler.  All of which means not using a text field unless I re-write a lot of the functionality I'd be losing if I treat the field as text instead of as a number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I shared in some of the comments, according to real math and JavaScript the following are true:

- `(1 == 1.)`
- `(1 === 1.)`
- `((1 + 1.) = 2)`

@nbk pointed out that according to the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-floating-point-number), `1.` is not a floating point number.

HTML is not capable of math - for this, we rely on JS.  JS believes `10.` is a real number, and a user will expect NOT to get an error if entered - just as it would be a real number on a calculator, or C++, or any other programming language.  Therefore I believe the HTML standard is "at fault" here, although I suppose someone has had this argument before me. (now I can't wait for the people taking umbrage at my use of "at fault.")

This is an issue if, like me, you are running `keydown` or `change` or some other method to do a running calculation based on the value of that field.  If you must enter `10.1` once you get to `10.` your script will bomb out with unplanned errors.

What I did was save a global variable and, if the value in the text field was valid, update the global and do calculations.  If the value is invalid, I skip reassignment and continue using the last value.  This does mean if you backspace over `10.1`, you will get the value of `10`.  If this is an issue, you can conditionally use rounding on the floating point number.

I do appreciate @nbk pointing me to the HTML standard.  I do not believe, as they do, that this is proper since the standards appear to conflict.  It might be "as planned," but it does create issues.  I'd have a better chance of a hot date with Jessica Alba than getting someone to change a standard as fully entrenched as HTML, so I'll leave this here as a note to the next pour soul who hits it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts that 1. is no number, but you defined the value as number, so the form send nothing to the javascript

change it to text and parsefloat will do its job correctly

```
<input id="myNumber" type="text">
```

see [fiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/65ughkaw/)

Comment: First, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. Your answer fails to address the question. I shared that I intend to use `checkValidity()` and `reportValidity()`, neither of which are possible as a number if I use text. Next, `console.log(1. + 2)` indeed reports the answer as `3` because `1. === 1 === 1.0` In addition, console.log(parseFloat("1.")) returns, correctly, 1. Finally, as I pointed out, there's either a Chrome or Safari/Firefox bug because the handling is different.

Comment: That isn't a bug, but if you feel so make an entry in the bugtracker, the behaviour is documented and so wanted, so you can find the commen denominator, or count for the different behaviours, and make your code depending on the browser, that is what frameworks do.. as far as i know all braowser accept text and you can check with parsefloat so if ot is a number

Comment: Documented where?  Because I can't seem to find it.

Comment: the browser interprets https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-floating-point-number  the specifics of every browser can vary. Like i said if you think it is a bug you can report it, but 1. is no valid number

Comment: Then there's a disconnect between actual math (and JavaScript) and the HTML standard dealing with numbers, because, I assure you, `1.` is a number in all worlds other than HTML.  Not to mention the different browser flavors.

Comment: no there isn't a number has to have a number at the start and at the end, i can not end with . or ,, take it as it is

Comment: I am not satisfied with this solution since I expect a number to be of type number, not text. We are using this input in a web view within our mobile application, and choosing type "text" will activate the standard keyboard of the operating system, which is not ideal since we need to open the number/tel keyboard.

Comment: @nbk how does mysql related to this? this is a pure front end issue

Comment: Sorry, i had the wrong idea, the problem is that javascript gets a NaN , using as text it will accept the value and you can convert it in your javascript with no effort